# javascript to jquery conversion for a code that is working fine for dynamic appearance and disappearance of a text field with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

guys I tried a lot for this code but nothing come up for conversion from javascript to jquery..

This code is irrelevant cuz u find this in working fiddle.. I added this chunk of code cuz stackoverflow dont allow me to post without a code..

```
<div class="rButtons">
<input type="radio" name="numbers" value="10" onclick="uncheck();" />10
<input type="radio" name="numbers" value="20"  onclick="uncheck();" />20
<input type="radio" name="numbers" value="other" onclick="check(this);"/>other
<input type="text" id="other_field" name="other_field" onblur="checktext(this);"/>
</div>
```

Check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gDxqj/

It is working well. on clicking "other" radio button the text field comes up and on clicking any other radio button it disappears.. This is the function of this script and it is working well..

Now when i tried changing it to jquery code it died.. I can show what code i made in jquery but to no help..

Fiddle for the same will help a lot..

Thanks in advance..

This is what i did

```
<script>
var $radios = $('input:radio[name=numbers]');
    if ($radios.is(':checked') === true) {
       $("#other_field").show();
    }     
    else
    {
       $("#other_field").hide();
    }   
</script>
```

I put it put that in a function and invoke it in "onchange" of radiobutton but not worked

Comment: Please show the example of what you tried that didn't work otherwise the SO police will come and give you a ticket for not showing "what you've tried".

Comment: If all other sites on the web died, SO would not be usable if everyone just stuck there code in a fiddle. This is why you should provide a code example of your work.

Comment: @ROY Finley please check now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(':radio').on('change', function () {
  $('#other_field')[$(this).val() === 'other' ? 'show' : 'hide']();
});

$('#other_field').on('blur', function () {
  var val = $(this).val();

  if(isNaN(val)) {
    alert('only numbers are allowed..');
  }
  else if(parseInt(val, 10) % 10 > 0) {
    alert('only multiples of 10..');
  }
});
```

with:

```
<div class="rButtons">
  <input type="radio" name="numbers" value="10" /> 10
  <input type="radio" name="numbers" value="20" /> 20
  <input type="radio" name="numbers" value="other" />other
  <input type="text" id="other_field" name="other_field" />
</div>
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BZGsw/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the `onclick` and `onblur` from your `input`s and attach the events through jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('.rButtons').on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function(ev){
        var val = $(this).val();
        val == 'other' ? check(this) : uncheck();
    });
    $('.rButtons').on('blur', '#other_field', function(ev){
        checktext(this);
    });
});
```

### [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gDxqj/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.change()` to bin the `change` event to check the state of the selected radio button then apply `.toggle()` on `#other_field` to show or hide it.

```
#other_field {
    display: none;
}
```

```
<div class="rButtons">
    <input type="radio" name="numbers" value="10">10
    <input type="radio" name="numbers" value="20">20
    <input type="radio" name="numbers" value="other">other
    <input type="text" id="other_field" name="other_field">
</div>
```

```
$("[name=numbers]").change(function() {
    $("#other_field").toggle(this.value === "other");
});
```

```
$("#other_field").change(checktext);
```

I modified your CSS to use `display` set to `none` instead of `visibility`.

[See it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/sPPpL/)